# Sum arrays in php file

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, smarty

I would like to know correct way to sum array when there is a function to put the arrays to smarty php.

PHP:

```
function stats($params)
{.....
    $values = implode(',', array_values($statistics));
    return $values;

}
```

Smarty PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
{stats type='applications' period='days' employer=$GLOBALS.current_user.username} 
</script>
```

will output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,405,47</script>
```

### Total is 458.

What I tried:

PHP:

```
$this->register_function('stats', array(&$this, 'stats'));
$this->register_function('sum_stats', array(&$this, 'sum_stats'));
function sum_stats($stats)
{
```

I copy completely code of $stats with the below:

```
    $values = array_sum($statistics);
    return $values;     
}
```

Smarty:

```
{sum_stats type='applications' period='days' employer=$GLOBALS.current_user.username}
```

Is that the correct way to do that? I got sum for 458 now...

Comment: Why must you get it from the template file ??? are you not the one outputting there in the first place ???

Comment: The code was customized by previous designer. I need the array to use in axis Y for flot chart... I thought it is enough for basis flot chart and I can sum it very easy w/o any skill...I have done line chart but I need sum for pie chart too...

Comment: Am a fan of smarty but i don't allowing it do the function of PHP ....  Am sure someone else would be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for not vote down since you are pure smarty fan...

Comment: Completely agree with Baba - sit down and rewrite your code, if you do this in template engine then it has no point!

Comment: So you got a way to output array for use in axis Y in flot chart?

Comment: Post problematic code completely...

Comment: I have change to php then assign a var to it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just pass it to array_sum. Like this:

PHP File:

`$smarty->assign('sum_this_array', array(0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,405,47));`

Smarty:

`{$sum_this_array|array_sum}`